# Correcting altered projection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

When I create a collection (named here `geeCol`) using Google Earth Engine, the projection displayed by `geeCol.first().projection().getInfo()` returns:

```
{'type': 'Projection', 'crs': 'EPSG:4326', 'transform': [0.25, 0.0, -180.0, 0.0, -0.25, 90.0]}
```

Based on this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283792/maximum-ndvi-for-3-months-average-in-google-earth-engine), I wrote a function that takes the average of multiple images within a time defined in days:

```
def makeComposite(collection, start, count, interval, units):
    sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(count).subtract(1)) # Create a sequence of numbers, one for each time interval. 
    originalStartDate = ee.Date(start) # Original start date
    
    def col(i):
        startDate = originalStartDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i), units)
        # Get the end date of the current sequence.
        endDate = originalStartDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)), units)
        return collection.filterDate(startDate, endDate).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
    return ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(col))
```

When I map this function on to my collection, the new projection is:

```
{'type': 'Projection', 'crs': 'EPSG:4326', 'transform': [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]}
```

Since  'crs' is preserved but 'transform' is changed, I am wondering if:

- This discrepancy really matters when I export my data to a csv
- If it does, what is the appropriate way of redefining the 'transform' field of the projection? Since the function does not appear to truly change the projection, is it a matter of (i) using `image.reproject()` or (ii) `image.setDefaultProjection()`?

In other terms, I am unsure whether it is a matter of re-projecting the entire image or just to correct a field that was lost.

Answer (score 2):

Per [Projections](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections#thedefaultprojection) page: "An image which is a composite or mosaic of input images with different projections will have the default projection, which is WGS84 with 1-degree scale"

Now, I don't believe the projections are different when you use the `reduce` method, but this has happened to me when I use the `mosaic()` method--the projection changes. In this case, I would explicitly reproject the output according to the transform you specified:

`image.reproject({'crs': 'EPSG:4326', 'crsTransform': [0.25, 0.0, -180.0, 0.0, -0.25, 90.0]})`